# C# get nesting Level of Tree

Tags: c#, recursion, nested

Let´s say I have two classes:

```
public Foo
{
   public List<Foo> Childs { get; set; }
   public Bar BarObj { get; set; }
   public int Level { get; set; }
}

public Bar
{
   public List<Foo> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to get the nesting-level from a Collection of "Foo" Objects

my current working Method looks like this:

```
int currentLevel = 0;
public void ApplyNestingLevel(List<Foo> list)
{
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        item.Level = currentLevel;
        if(item.Childs.Count > 0 || item.BarObj.Childs.Count > 0)
        {
            currentLevel++;
        }
        ApplyNestingLevel(item.Childs);
        ApplyNestingLevel(item.BarObj.Childs);
    }
}
```

how could I make this more "elegant/simple" ?

Comment: Maybe you could read about visitor pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: I don't see the "Else" property in Foo.

Comment: oops sorry my bad...typo

Answer (score 3):

Store a reference to the parent and make the Level property recursive.

I added an example and a couple other design suggestions in the code sample below.  Hope this helps.  FYI, this is pretty much straight out of the Gang of Four's design for the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), which should be required reading for anyone who is serious about OOP.

- [DoFactory .NET Composite Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternComposite.aspx)
- [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software, on Amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

  ```
      public class Foo
      {

          public Foo(Foo parent = default(Foo))
          { 
              this.parent = parent;
              this.children = new List<Foo>();
          }

          private readonly Foo parent;
          private readonly List<Foo> children;

          public int Level { get { return ReferenceEquals(parent,null) ? 0 : parent.Level + 1; } }

          // don't expose the actual list... see below for why
          public IEnumerable<Foo> Children { get { foreach(Foo child in this.children) yield return child; } }

          //  instead of exposing the child object list
          //  declare an explicit method with any parameters 
          //  necessary.  this allows you to enforce the invariant 
          //  condition that all objects in a children collection
          //  will have their parent reference set to their 
          //  actual parent
          public void AddChild()
          {
              Foo newChild = new Foo(parent:this);
              this.children.Add(newChild);
          }

          //  if you need the ability to remove items as well, 
          //  you can expose a remove method too.  Just make 
          //  sure that you validate expected preconditions
          public int RemoveChild(Foo childToRemove)
          { 
              if(ReferenceEquals(childToRemove,null)) throw new ArgumentNullException("childToRemove");
              if(!ReferenceEquals(this,childToRemove.parent)) throw new ArgumentException("The object cannot be removed because the current object is not the correct parent.","childToRemove"); 
              return children.RemoveAll((Foo existentChild) => existentChild.Equals(childToRemove));
          }


      }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void ApplyNestingLevel(Foo f)
{
    ApplyNestingLevel(f, 0);
}


public void ApplyNestingLevel(Foo f, int level)
{
    if(f == null) { return; }
    f.Level = level
    if(f.Childs != null) {
        foreach(Foo child in f.Childs)
        {
            ApplyNestingLevel(child, level + 1);
        }
    }
    if(f.BarObj != null && f.BarObj.Childs != null) {
        foreach(Foo child in f.BarObj.Childs)
        {
            ApplyNestingLevel(child, level + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my version, i using extensions.

```
    public static class EnumerableExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>Get max nesting level.</summary>
        /// <param name="source">Source.</param>
        /// <param name="children">Selector.</param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type.</typeparam>
        /// <returns><see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/>.</returns>
        public static int GetMaxNestingLevel<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> children)
        {
            return source.SelectMany(x => GetNestingLevel(x, 0)).Max();

            IEnumerable<int> GetNestingLevel(T source, int level)
            {
                if (children(source) != null)
                {
                    return children(source).SelectMany(x => GetNestingLevel(x, level + 1));
                }
                else
                {
                    return new List<int> { level } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

than u can use it like

```
  var max = Foo.Childs.GetMaxNestingLevel(x => x.Childs);
```

ps
mayby you need tests (NUnit)

```
    using NUnit.Framework;
    ....
    public class EnumerableExtensionsTests
    {
        private static IEnumerable GetMaxNestingLevelTestCases
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new TestCaseData(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }).Returns(4);
                yield return new TestCaseData(new int[] { 4, 3, 2, 1 }).Returns(4);
                yield return new TestCaseData(new int[] { 1, 10, 0, 1 }).Returns(10);
                yield return new TestCaseData(new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }).Returns(1);
                yield return new TestCaseData(new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 2 }).Returns(2);
            }
        }

        [TestCaseSource(nameof(GetMaxNestingLevelTestCases))]
        public int GetMaxNestingLevelTest(ICollection<int> sourceNestingLevel)
        {
            var testSource = sourceNestingLevel.Select(x => new NestingLevelTestClass(x)).ToList();

            return testSource.GetMaxNestingLevel(x => x.Children);
        }

        private class NestingLevelTestClass
        {
            public NestingLevelTestClass(int childrenLevel = 0)
            {
                if (childrenLevel != 0)
                {
                    Children = new List<NestingLevelTestClass>
                    {
                        new NestingLevelTestClass(childrenLevel - 1),
                    };
                }
            }

            public ICollection<NestingLevelTestClass> Children { get; set; }
        }
    }
```